# Making deb package for a few commands

Tags: package-management, dpkg, deb, packaging

I want to make a package to execute a few commands.

The first option I considered was making a `postinst` file.

But it seems that thus would be executed **after** the package is installed, so if that script fails, the package will be installed but in a broken state!

The second option is using a `Makefile`, but it seems that this is executed during the build process of the package, not during its installation.

The last option was using an `install` file, but it seems that in that case I need to make a separate script file for just a few commands, copy them into some path, and have that script executed by `postinst`.

Is there another option to do this?

Comment: Also preinstall scripts are possible? What am I missing in your question? What do you really want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

- Yes, you can use `postinst` to run onetime (setup/configuration) script.

  Just, don't use `set -e` or directly disable exit on error `set +e`.
- It is also possible to catch & handle errors using conditional instructions like `if`, `||`, ...
- After that, you can still make and offer same setup script to the user with other runtime tools. If it fails on setup and was skipped. End user can always rerun it or try debug it. Something like `locatedb` (or `updatedb` in some systems) from `locate`, it is run by APT and also available for user.

Just make the scripts report error messages to users, so they know what happening and what to be done next.